# Android intent to other Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to forward from current activity to other Activity. But when i click the button i am not able to perform it.I want to move from MainActivity to FeedActivity Please tell what is fault in my code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sample.test.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/button2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Welcome to android by Vivek", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FeedActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: instead of `view.getContext(),` use `MainActivity.this`

Comment: if i use MainActivity.this it gives error as it doesnt allow in onClick

Comment: `instead of view.getContext(), use MainActivity.this` and what for? ... question is: are you clicking the right button?

Comment: for intent to specify the current class and yest i am clicking the right one

Comment: does your button click event fire ? use log/toast to check wheather onclick event fires or not ? and if yes ..and any exception occur...post it

Comment: i tried a toast and it works

Comment: do you have any exceptions when you try to start new activity?
what do you have in your log?

Comment: no i dont have exceptions

Comment: Please post your manifest in the question. Also post the `onCreate()` of `FeedActivity`. Have you checked the logcat for errors? Don't filter the logcat as you might miss something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating a new instance of Intent, you need to give it two parameters:

- current activity class instance
- goto activity class instance

Also, you need to either import View library or use your `new OnClickListener` as `new View.OnClickListener`

You can do that by adding this to import:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Change your `btn2.onClickListener` to :

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FeedActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: lol, `view.getContext() == MainActivity.this`(or it is ContextThemeWrapper but still it doesn't matter and using view.getContext() is valid at this place)  the problem is not here!

Comment: I have run this code successfully, can you provide your complete `MainActivity` class code? also `activity_main.xml` contains a string element for `button2` text. Have you put in String variable for that?